# how to display pagination on bottom of page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, will-paginate

while the global for the pagination is currently set up as the following:

```
 .pagination {
     float: right !important;
     display: inline-block;
     padding-left: 0;
     margin: 20px 0;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

again, on the other pages it's correctly displayed on the bottom on the page, however, on this particular page with the same exact css, the pagination is at the top where again, I need it at the bottom.

Comment: I'd love to see all your code for the page, but I'd venture to guess because you're floating this to the right it will default to the top right of the page unless you are clearing floats on all other containers above it.

Comment: thanks for reaching out, I'm floating to the right, coz I have these business analysts thinking they're UX designers wanting me to move it right, and positioned on the bottom of the page, or table, and I can't figure it out. and believe me, I don't think you'd love to see the code.

Comment: It's hard to help without code... I guess you inserted all relevant code for pagination (something like <%= will_paginate... %>) at the bottom, or at least at the same place of your pages?

Comment: correct. it's done in haml actually, and = will_paginate filtered_documents, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails is currently at the bottom of the index.html.haml page but for some reason on the top of this particular page where the other pagination resides on the bottom.

Comment: got it, but thanks to all who helped.

Comment: I still think it's probably just a matter of clearing your floats; float right with a bunch of uncleared divs will default nearer the top of the screen, arranged according to other floated elements it's near/in the same div with.

Comment: this issue is simply because the haml wasn't properly in nested, though it did take about 4 hours to figure this out, and many thanks for everyone who reached out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at this snippet which is the full code needed for a data table with pagination at the bottom.
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-snipp-for-datatable